# Wifi, DNS problem on MacBook Pro retina

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, dns

On a Macbook Pro retina 13 2014 with El Capitan 10.11.5 I can't access websites through their domain name (google.com, bing.com, etc).

I can access the internet with Google Chrome, but with others applications I can't.

I can ping 8.8.8.8:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ alex$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=18.093 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=18.489 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 18.093/18.291/18.489/0.198 ms
MacBook-Pro:~ alex$
```

I can't ping google.com

```
MacBook-Pro:~ alex$ ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host
MacBook-Pro:~ alex$
```

I tried to put DNS manually (8.8.8.8), reboot, but it doesn't work.

I tried to delete these files and reboot but it doesn't work:

- com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
- com.apple.network.identification.plist`
- NetworkInterfaces.plist`
- preferences.plist`

tried:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ alex$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9734
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     264 IN  A   172.217.16.68

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 14 16:00:31 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48

MacBook-Pro:~ alex$
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Google Chrome uses its own DNS resolver, that's why it behaves differently.
2. `dig` command also connects directly to DNS server.
3. To verify your current DNS server settings on the `Wi-Fi` network interface use:

   ```
   networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
   ```
4. To troubleshoot your problem try:

   1. clearing the DNS server settings (and rely on DHCP) with:

      ```
      sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi empty
      ```
   2. setting the DNS server manually with the command:

      ```
      sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
      ```
   3. create a new location with separate DNS settings by:

      - clicking on the network icon in the menu bar
      - choosing **Open Network Preferences...**
      - selecting **Edit Locations...** from the top list box (you might need to unlock settings with administrator's password first) and creating new location
      - clicking on **Advanced...** button, selecting **DNS** tab and adding the DNS servers in the left pane