# Resolving host...: Internet doesn't work (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: network, dns

My MacBook sometimes can't connect to the internet. Chrome displays "Resolving host" but a web page doesn't appear. Safari also doesn't work. Interestingly, sometimes Google seems to work as the only web page (also auto complete in Google). After some time (or sometimes when I call "`dscacheutil -flushcache`") it works for a few minutes and then the issue occurs again.

Other devices always work so it has to be related to my MacBook. I'm using two DNS servers pointing to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4. When the issue is present Ping doesn't work (`ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host`) and Lookup doesn't work too (`www.google.com -> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)`)

A few month ago I had the same issue. At the time I had to delete some files in the LaunchDeamons-folder but I can't remember which ones...

Anything I could try?

Update: If I add a second "Location" (in the Network preferences) I can simply switch to the other location and I'm back in the Internet... pretty tedious solution...

Comment: How about settings I described here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245986/145449 the situation is different, but these would be first things to try.

Comment: I just tried but after a few minutes the problem is back...

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, does the problem exist if you connect via Ethernet?  Can you test that out?

Comment: Yes, this seems to work but this not really an option...

Comment: If it works in Ethernet (on the same network), the problem isn't related to DNS.  The issue is the adapter.  To prove this, try a [USB WiFi adapter](http://amzn.to/2vy2LRW) - a cheap one (or better yet borrowed) will do fine since it's for testing.  If the problem goes away, it's your WiFi Airport card.

Answer (score 1):

Does the issue eventually come back when creating another location? If not, this is being caused by settings.

Comment: I use two locations as a workaround. Whenever I switch locations it works again for some minutes.